# Empty list for users who are in Teams, but with no shared teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams, user-interface

Users have a *Profiles* dropdown list on their profile:

[image: Menu with "Meta user" and "Network profile"]

If you share a Team with the user you're looking at, there's a menu item for it:

[image: Menu with "Meta user" and "Network profile" and a Teams section with "Smitop Dev"]

But for some users, there's the "TEAMS" heading but no Teams:

[image: Menu with "Meta user" and "Network profile" and an empty Teams section]

This appears to occur when users are in a Team, but I don't have any Teams in common with them. I think it would be better to just not show the Teams section at all in this menu.